# How to slow down box2d body linear or angular velocity

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, velocity

I have a circle shape dynamic body that simulates a bouncing ball, I set the restitution to 2 and it just gets out of control to the point it does't stop from bouncing up and down. So I want to slow down the ball linear or angular velocity using Damping.

```
if(ball.getLinearVelocity().x >= 80 || ball.getLinearVelocity().y >= 80)
            ball.setLinearDamping(50)
else if(ball.getLinearVelocity().x <= -80 || ball.getLinearVelocity().y <=-80)
            ball.setLinearDamping(50);
```

When the linear velocity of the ball reaches 80 or above I set its linear Damping to 50 then it  just goes super slow motion. Can someone please explain me how Damping works and how to use `.setLinearDamping()` method properly, thanks.

**EDIT**

This is what I did, if the linear velocity exceeded from what I need it sets the ball linear Damping to 20 if not always set it to 0.5f. This creates and effect that the gravity changes constantly and instantly. However @minos23 answer is correct because it simulates the ball more naturally you just need to set the MAX_VELOCITY that you need.

```
 if(ball.getLinearVelocity().y >= 30 || ball.getLinearVelocity().y <= -30)
            ball.setLinearDamping(20);
        else if(ball.getLinearVelocity().x >= 30 || ball.getLinearVelocity().x <= -30)
            ball.setLinearDamping(20);
        else
            ball.setLinearDamping(0.5f);
```

Comment: please tell us if the solutions provided worked for you, if any trouble leave a comment , good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what i uselly do to limit the velocity of the body :

```
if(ball.getLinearVelocity().x >= MAX_VELOCITY)
      ball.setLinearVelocity(MAX_VELOCITY,ball.getLinearVelocity().y)
if(ball.getLinearVelocity().x <= -MAX_VELOCITY)
      ball.setLinearVelocity(-MAX_VELOCITY,ball.getLinearVelocity().y);
if(ball.getLinearVelocity().y >= MAX_VELOCITY)
      ball.setLinearVelocity(ball.getLinearVelocity().x,MAX_VELOCITY)
if(ball.getLinearVelocity().y <= -MAX_VELOCITY)
      ball.setLinearVelocity(ball.getLinearVelocity().x,-MAX_VELOCITY);
```

try this code inside the **render()** method please and it will limit the speed of the ball body that you're making

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Your code sets up a strong linear damping, but never releases it, so when the ball reaches a specific speed, it will switch to a state in which it behaves like it's glued.

I would rather limit the maximum speed by checking and resetting it if necessary in every frame:

```
float maxLength2 = 80*80;
Vector2 v = ball.getLinearVelocity();
if (v.len2() > maxLength2) {
    v.setLength2(maxLength2);
}
```

#### How linear damping works

Linear damping imitates the phenomenon called [drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)) when the objects moves not too fast. It is basically described by the following equation in every moment:

```
dragInducedForce = -dragCoefficient * velocity;
```

Comment: thanks I tried your code but the ball linear velocity still surpasses the maxLenght2

Comment: do you execute the snippet in every frame?

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbee, how do you execute the snippet?

Comment: @StormAsdg Replace the code in your question with the code in my answer